# How to annotate a type that's a class object (instead of a class instance)?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

What is the proper way to annotate a function argument that expects a class object instead of an instance of that class?

In the example below, `some_class` argument is expected to be a type instance (which is a class), but the problem here is that `type` is too broad:

```
def construct(some_class: type, related_data:Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
    ...
```

In the case where `some_class` expects a specific set of types objects, using `type` does not help at all. The `typing` module might be in need of a Class generic that does this:

```
def construct(some_class: Class[Union[Foo, Bar, Baz]], related_data:Dict[str, Any]) -> Union[Foo, Bar, Baz]:
    ...
```

In the example above, `some_class` is the `Foo`, `Bar` or `Faz` class, not an instance of it. It should not matter their positions in the class tree because `some_class: Class[Foo]` should also be a valid case. Therefore,

```
# classes are callable, so it is OK
inst = some_class(**related_data)
```

or

```
# instances does not have __name__
clsname = some_class.__name__
```

or

```
# an operation that only Foo, Bar and Baz can perform.
some_class.a_common_classmethod()
```

should be OK to mypy, pytype, PyCharm, etc.

How can this be done with current implementation (Python 3.6 or earlier)?

Comment: If you need to be more specific than `type`, either introduce a metaclass or an abstract base class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - A metaclass would do the trick, i believe, but I haven't reached this level in Python yet. With the introduction of variable annotations in 3.6 (including a `ClassVar` to differ instance variables from class variables), I wonder why should I use `type` to annotate class objects when there are so many ways to annotate class instances. Maybe I'll have to wait for a future update or a recipe :).

Comment: It seems I'll have to rely on `typing.Type` and do something like `Foo = TypeVar['Foo', bond=Bar]`, where `Bar` is an ABC, then, taking the example above: `def construct(some_class: Type[Foo], ...) -> Foo`. I particularly don't like having to use `TypeVar`, but it seems to be the only way...

Answer (score 154, accepted):

To annotate an object that is a class, use [`typing.Type`](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects). For example, this would tell the type checker that `some_class` is class `Foo` or any of its subclasses:

```
from typing import Type
class Foo: ...
class Bar(Foo): ...
class Baz: ...
some_class: Type[Foo]
some_class = Foo # ok
some_class = Bar # ok
some_class = Baz # error
some_class = Foo() # error
```

Note that `Type[Union[Foo, Bar, Baz]]` and `Union[Type[Foo], Type[Bar], Type[Baz]]` are completely equivalent.

If `some_class` could be any of a number of classes, you may want to make them all inherit from the same base class, and use `Type[BaseClass]`. Note that the inheritance must be non-virtual for now (mypy support for virtual inheritance is [being discussed](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2922)).

Edited to confirm that `Type[Union[...` is allowed.

Comment: Is it safer to use `Union[Type[Class], Type[ClassB]]` or `Type[Union[ClassA, ClassB]]`? I would default to the first choice.

Comment: Starting with Python 3.9 `typing.Type` is deprecated since you can now use `type[MyClass]` (though mypy has problems with it while it is fine for Pylance). With Python 3.10 the Union expression with `|` was introduced. So now it is possible to write `type[ClassA] | type[ClassB]` or `type[ClassA | ClassB]`.

Comment: If you want to use any class try: variable: class