# Type of a returned class

Tags: python, python-typing

**Update**: as chepner points out in the comments, creating the class in the function is a bad idea, it performs ten to eighty times slower than other solutions. See the performance comparison in my self-answer, which also shows how to do the typing.

---

I do this:

```py
def get_an_x():
    class X:
        foo = 1
        bar = 'Hello'
        baz = None
    return X
```

`get_an_x` returns a class `X`, which serves as a plain structure.

What is the type of this class `X`? Doing `def get_an_x() -> type: ...` (that what `type(X)` returns) will not work, then PyCharms's type checker does not detect the attributes of `X`. Annotating the attributes with `ClassVar[...]` also does not help.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43457817/1658543), but doing `def get_an_x() -> type[X]: ...` does not work, because I define the class inside the function, and it is not seen from outside.

Comment: Why are you defining a class solely to contain class attributes, instead of using a named tuple?

Comment: There's also `types.SimpleNamespace`. In any event, you should define a class *outside* your function, and have your function return an *instance* of that type. All you seem to care about is something that has attributes, so there's no real reason for that something to be a class.

Comment: Got you. I now do it with a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which performs much faster, and it is less syntax when we include the typing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

Creating a class in a function and returning it, is a bad idea. It is very slow. There are other ways to do this:

```py
### INITIALISATION


## CLASS INSTANCE
# Structural type info, fastest (except simple tuples).

class MyInstance:
  __slots__ = ['foo', 'bar']
  def __init__(self, foo: int, bar: str):
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar


## DATA CLASS
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html
# Structural type info, fast.

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
  foo: int
  bar: str


## SIMPLE NAMESPACE
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace
# No structural type info, fast.
# The structure can change, it is useful when working with JSON, see e.g.
# https://medium.com/@shashank_iyer/
#   simplify-json-access-with-simplenamespace-e91f5a09345b

from types import SimpleNamespace


## NAMED TUPLE
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple
# Structural type info, slightly slower than above solutions.
# It is a tuple under the hood.

from typing import NamedTuple

MyNamedTuple = NamedTuple('MyNamedTuple', foo=int, bar=str)


## CLASS WITH PROTOCOL (not recommened)
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol
# Structural type info, 10 to 80 times slower than above solutions!

from typing import Protocol

class MyClass(Protocol):
  foo: int
  bar: str

def make_my_class(fooparam: int, barparam: str) -> MyClass:
  class my_class:
    foo = fooparam
    bar = barparam
  return my_class



### USAGE


## PERFORMANCE

from timeit import timeit

def performance(it, does, times=1_000_000):
  timing = timeit(does, number=times)
  print(f"{it:<12} {timing:6.3f}")

performance('instance', lambda: MyInstance(1, 'Hello'))
performance('dataclass', lambda: MyDataclass(1, 'Hello'))
performance('namespace', lambda: SimpleNamespace(foo=1, bar='Hello'))
performance('namedtuple', lambda: MyNamedTuple(foo=1, bar='Hello'))
performance('class', lambda: make_my_class(fooparam=1, barparam='Hello'))

# For comparision, the performance of simple datatypes
performance('tuple', lambda: (1, 'Hello'))
performance('list', lambda: [1, 'Hello'])
performance('dict', lambda: {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'Hello'})
performance('set', lambda: {1, 'Hello'})


## RESULTS

# instance      0.478
# dataclass     0.568
# namespace     0.483
# namedtuple    0.796
# class        14.904  # varies between 10 and 25 seconds
# tuple         0.344
# list          0.591
# dict          0.666
# set           0.707
```

#### Original Answer

[Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol), suggested by abel1502, seems to do what I want:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class X(Protocol):
  foo: str
  bar: int
  baz: None

def get_an_x() -> X:

  class x:
    foo = 'the answer'
    bar = 42
    baz = None

  return x
```

Now PyCharms type checker detects wrong types and non-existing or unknown attributes:

```py
# These are ok

x: X = get_an_x()

foo: str = x.foo
bar: int = x.bar
baz: None = x.baz

# These are type errors

unknown = x.unknownattribute
wrong_type: int = x.foo
wrong_x: str = get_an_x()

def get_a_wrong_x() -> X:

  class x:
    foox = 'the answer'
    bar = '42'

  return x
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, every time you call `foo`, it returns a different class. If it had a base class, you could annotate it with `typing.Type[Base]`, to at least show the base's attributes. But in your situation I'd suggest you to either let your IDE figure it out without annotations, or to annotate it as `typing.Type`.

One more option you have is creating a [protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol), if you know the exact attribute set in advance, and using it for the annotation

Comment: Sorry, I have to unaccept it, even if it is helpful. My idea to create a class in a function is bad.